# D3 JS - tick spacing on time axis gets messed up by month boundary

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using d3.js, I found that when using a time scale for the x-axis, the major tick marks get messed up on a new month boundary. It appears to create a new tick mark on the new month even if that results in a tick too close to the previous tick. Not only does this mess up the even spacing along the axis, it also makes the tick labels overlap and look pretty ugly.

See the demo at the bottom of the question to show what I mean (scroll to the right to see the problem area).

Do I need [a custom multi-scale time format](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176) to handle this case? Or is there some option I'm missing here? (And is this considered a bug?)

EDIT: I tried out the custom multi-time format, and it does work to change the extra label from just "June" to match the others, but it still shows up where it shouldn't. The problem is that there shouldn't be a tick mark there at all; it should keep the same 2-day spacing between ticks that was always there, and it's not. I'm leaning toward calling this a bug.

Here's a demo where this happens:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      body {
        font: 12px Arial;
      }
      path {
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2;
        fill: none;
      }
      .axis path, .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: grey;
        stroke-width: 1;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      }
    </style>
    <body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.2.2/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = {
            "values" : [40, 80, 94, 95, 10, 81, 89, 70, 43, 56, 86, 72, 39, 38, 84, 5, 0, 38, 68, 16, 23, 6, 45, 7, 79, 59, 51, 33, 44, 18],
            "labels" : ["2013,05,07", "2013,05,08", "2013,05,09", "2013,05,10", "2013,05,11", "2013,05,12", "2013,05,13", "2013,05,14", "2013,05,15", "2013,05,16", "2013,05,17", "2013,05,18", "2013,05,19", "2013,05,20", "2013,05,21", "2013,05,22", "2013,05,23", "2013,05,24", "2013,05,25", "2013,05,26", "2013,05,27", "2013,05,28", "2013,05,29", "2013,05,30", "2013,05,31", "2013,06,01", "2013,06,02", "2013,06,03", "2013,06,04", "2013,06,05"]
        };
    
        var margin = { top : 15, right : 15, bottom : 40, left : 50 },
            width = 750 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
        // Parse dates
        data.parsedDates = [];
        data.labels.forEach(function(d) {
            var parsed = d3.time.format("%Y,%m,%d").parse(d);
            data.parsedDates.push(parsed);
        });
    
        var x = d3.time.scale()
            .range([0, width])
            .domain(d3.extent(data.parsedDates));
    
        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0])
            .domain(d3.extent(data.values));
    
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
            .ticks(8).tickSize(5, 0, 0);
    
        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d,i) {
                return x(data.parsedDates[i]); })
            .y(function(d,i) {
                return y(d); });
    
        // Create chart
        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
        // Graph points
        svg.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values) });
    
        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);
      </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Yes, you need to create a multi-scale time format for this. I'm not sure if this is to be considered a bug though.

Comment: You can rotate the x labels -90 degrees, so they don't overlap.

Comment: @mjjohnson Did you ever find a solution to this problem? http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: @Joshua Alas, it's been long enough that I don't remember what I did...I'm not even completely sure I found an answer. Good xkcd, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that manual dates selection is the only possible solution for current D3 version, 5.12.0 as for answer date (P.S. solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39130737)):

```
const xValues = data.filter((d, i) => i % interval === 0).map(d => d.date);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %d'))
// .ticks(d3.timeDay.every(interval))
.tickValues(xValues);
```