# Why does my d3 chart's x-axis include the first of every month as a tick even though I set the tick interval to every 7 days?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart, axes

I am new to d3 but I have set the tick interval for my x-axis to every 7 days using `d3.timeDay.every(7)`. However when my graph is created, I also see a tick mark added for the first of every month. For example, [my graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVWed.png) shows ticks at 10/1, 10/8, 10/15, 10/22, 10/29, and 11/1, even though 11/1 is not 7 days after 10/29. If I expand this range to include multiple months, I see a tick at the first of every month.

I have included my code for this axis below. What might be causing the first of each month to be displayed as a tick?

```
  const xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0, innerWidth]);
  const tickAmount = d3.timeDay.every(7);

  chart.append("g")
    .classed('x-axis', true)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerHeight + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    .ticks(tickAmount)
    .tickSize(-innerHeight)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%m/%d/%y')));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `const tickAmount = d3.timeWeek.every(1);` instead:

> Note that for some intervals, the resulting dates may not be uniformly-spaced; d3.timeDay’s parent interval is d3.timeMonth, and thus the interval number resets at the start of each month. If step is not valid, returns null. If step is one, returns this interval. [from the d3 docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/b898f28b50d76cc432df3f356cac5b73e7be3d69/README.md#interval_every)

<strike>You can also use `.tickFormat(function(d, i) { return d; })` to filter out given ticks from display if you like (e.g. exclude first tick: `return i>0 ? d : ''`), though this is more hacky.</strike>

Found a better way to do this [from d3 issue tracker](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2240#issuecomment-118582280):

```
d3.axisBottom(x)
  .ticks(d3.timeDay.filter(d=>d3.timeDay.count(0, d) % N === 0))
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%m/%d/%y'))
  .tickSizeOuter(0)
```

This will give you consistent ticks every N-th day without the months repeating. That a tick exists does not mean a point exists at that date in your dataset, but they are scaled correctly over the date range.

Here's a demo: https://beta.observablehq.com/@thmsdnnr/d3-ticks-every-7-or-10-days

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out. Using `timeWeek` fixed the issue and works perfectly for my 7 day intervals. I also have two more charts with ticks every 10 days and every 15 days. Do you have any suggestions for removing the start of month ticks for these graphs? I can try to come up with something using `.tickFormat`

Comment: I *think* I figured this out — I edited my answer and included a demo. Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

Comment: Just lost a few hours on this. Thanks for this answer! I still don't understand why this is not like this by default tbh...